# How can I add some delay to my gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to create a pipeline that plays a file into my headphones and an audiomixer that mixes the output of my mic and the audio from the file, then piles that into a virtual audio cable.

In other words, file+mic go to virtual cable, file also goes to headphones.

I'm noticing some latency where if I speak in time with the audio from the file that I'm hearing in my headphones, the output of my mic is not in sync with the audio from the file when it comes out of the mixer.

It seems like I should be able to address this by adding a delay to the audio from the file as it enters the mixer, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I've tried adding a queue with a min-threshold-time but it isn't working.

Here's my pipeline so far:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe filesrc location="C:/file.mp4" ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! volume volume=0.25 ! tee name=t ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 min-threshold-time=1000000000 ! audiomixer name=mix alignment-threshold=0 ! queue ! wasapisink device="virtual cable sink" \
wasapisrc device="mic" low-latency=true ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! volume volume=4 ! mix.
t. ! queue! wasapisink device="headphones"
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was able to find you have 3 options:

i) Implement a buffer probe which will enable you to modify the timestamps of individual packets. See [Pipeline Manipulation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html?gi-language=c).

ii) Use G-Streamer's plugin [`rtpjitterbuffer`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtpjitterbuffer.html#GstRtpJitterBuffer--ts-offset) that has a `ts-offset` property that can be used to adjust the timestamp of mic input in order to achieve sync between sources:

iii) Add latency to the pipeline like:

```
pipeline  = gst_pipeline_new ("mypipe"); 
gstpipline=GST_PIPELINE (pipeline); 
gst_pipeline_set_latency(gstpipline,delay you want to set in ns);
```